# How to update records from database displayed in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have code like this in product.php:

```
class Product {
private $conn;
private $id;
private $name;
private $description;
private $price;
private $category_id;
private $category_name;
private $created;


public function __construct($db) {
    $this->conn = $db;
}

public function readAll()
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT id, name, description, price, CategoryID, created FROM products');
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "<form action=\"./objects/product.php\" method=\"post\"> <table class=\"highlight responsive-table\">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field=\"empty\"> </th>
                <th data-field=\"name\">Name</th>
                <th data-field=\"description\">Description</th>
                <th data-field=\"price\">Price</th>
                <th data-field=\"category\">Category</th>
                <th data-field=\"action\">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>";

    while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $result['id'];
        $n = $result['name'];
        $d = $result['description'];
        $p = $result['price'];
        $ca = $result['CategoryID'];
        $c = $result['created'];

        echo "<tbody>
             <tr>
             <td style=\"width:10%;\">

                        <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox_".$id."\" name=\"checkbox[]\" value=".$id." />
                        <label for=\"checkbox_".$id."\"></label>

                </td>



                <td style=\"width:15%;\">" .$n. "</td>
                <td style=\"width:30%;\">" . $d. "</td>
                <td style=\"width:10%;\">" ."$".$p. "</td>
                <td style=\"width:15%;\">" . $ca. "</td>
                <td style=\"width:20%;\"> 
                    <a class=\"waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger\" href=\"#modal2\" id=\"edit_".$id."\" name=\"edit[]\"><i class=\"material-icons\">mode_edit</i></a>
                    <a class=\"waves-effect waves-light btn\"><i class=\"material-icons\">delete</i></a>
                </td>";
    }
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Delete\" name=\"delete\" id=\"delete\"/>
    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"update\" name=\"update\" id=\"update\"/>
    </form>";
    echo "</tbody> </table>";


}

public function deleteSelected($ids) {
    $query = 'DELETE FROM products WHERE id=?';

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    if (is_array($ids)) {
        foreach ($ids as $id)
            $stmt->execute([$id]);
    }
    else {
        $stmt->execute([$ids]);
    }
}

public function update() {
    $sql2= "UPDATE `products` SET `Name` = :name, `Description` = :description, `Price` = :price, `CategoryID` = :catid WHERE `products`.`ID` = :id";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql2);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':description', $_POST['description'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':price', $_POST['price'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':catid', $_POST['catid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
}

} 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

if ( isset( $_POST['delete']) && !empty( $_POST['checkbox']) ) {
    $checkboxArr = $_POST['checkbox'];
    foreach($checkboxArr as $id)
    {
        $cat = new Product($conn);

        $cat->deleteSelected($id);
    }
}

if ( isset( $_POST['update']) && !empty( $_POST['edit']) ) {
    $editArr = $_POST['edit'];

        $cat = new Product($conn);

        $cat->update();

}

}
```

update button in index.php:

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="update" style="float:left; margin: 5px;">
         <i class="material-icons left">mode_edit</i>Update
</button>
```

I'm displaying content of database in a table in index.php using readAll function. In 1st column I have checkbox. On the page are also few buttons, one of them is supposed to open dialog window for editing record by using "update" function. I tried to do that same way as by deleting records from database but it's not working. What is wrong in that code?

Answer (score 1):

The only wrong thing in the code is the logic. From the last `foreach` I can infer that the user has a list of products, checks some checkboxes and then clicks on the `update` button, when a popup appears to update the product. I tend to believe that the popup contains fields for just one product at a time, not for all the products the user checked.

You should probably put an update button for each product, so that when a user clicks it they will know what product will be updated. Also, when the button will be clicked, the popup window can be filled with the existing data to be updated.

In the scenario that I propose, you won't need that last `foreach`, because you'll only update a single product.

**Conclusion**
The error is in the HTML and the way the data for a product to be updated is sent, not in the shown PHP code.

Comment: Yeah, there is a table with products, for each product there is also a checkbox and an `edit` button, when clicked popup appears, there is a form for one product and `Update` button. So, I deleted that `foreach`, and I tried to do that without checking checkboxes, just by clicking `edit` button for selected product, so I added to that button `id=\"edit_".$id."\" name=\"edit[]\"`, similar to the checkbox, but it's still not working, and I still don't get where is the error. I also edited the question with changes I made